# ASP Net Core Identity постоянно пропадает авторизация

Tags: asp.net-core

Имеется сайт vhealth.ru. Написан на ASP Net Core 3.1. Есть система авторизации ASP Net Core Identity. Сервер от reg.ru. Суть вопроса в том, что постоянно приходится проходить авторизацию заново, даже при небольшом простое. Cookie файлы на месте и имеет достаточный срок годности
Вот пример кода входа:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
                if (user != null)
                {
                    // проверяем, подтвержден ли email
                    if (!await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Вы не подтвердили свой email");
                        return View(model);
                    }
                }
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    // проверяем, принадлежит ли URL приложению
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Неправильный логин и (или) пароль");
                }
            }
```

Так же авторизация слетает при перезапуске приложения, например после простоя. Потратил уже несколько дней в поисках ответа, но так ничего и не нашел.
При тестировании приложения всё работает исправно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может быть, это глупый вопрос от меня, но я не вижу, чтобы `ModelState.IsValid` был установлен где-либо в вашем коде

Comment: ModelState.IsValid стоит первой строкой. И это никакого отношения не имеет. ModelState.IsValid - это просто проверка модели на соответствие требованиям.